# Обработка долгого прикосновения

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Через какие события в onTouch/onTouchEvent (или любыми другими средствами) можно отловить долгое нажатие?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919865/detecting-a-long-press-with-android)
Прокомментирую: создаете GestureDetector, который будет ловить долгие нажатия. Далее, добавляете на канву onTouchListener, а результат возвращаете в виде вызова метода детектора onTochEvent.

Answer (score 4):

```
something.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) { ... } });
```

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, мне нужно знать точные координаты нажатия, т.к. нажатие происходит по нарисованной на Canvas поверхности.

Comment: Вопрос надо формулировать точнее!

Answer (score 0):

Для получения координат юзай [`getX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX()) и [`getY()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getY())

Comment: Сам onLongClick не вызывается вообще.